# Any advice on copying an entire REST API into a database and keep it updated?

Tags: database, integration, jobs

I have the need to create an application that will fully copy the contents of an external REST API endpoint to a relational database. For the sake of example, let's say I am copying a list of movies from a REST API.

Every two hours, the application will:

1. Run a script that will fetch ALL movies from this REST endpoint (can be up to 300,000 entries)
2. Wipe out all the contents of the database (the database, before the wipe out, possibly contained outdated movie entries)
3. Save ALL the movies retrieved in step 1 in the database

The objective is to ensure that the movies database is no more than two hours in conflict with the contents of the original movies REST API.
I tried to find some best practices for doing this copying, but could not find any literature that was related to this use case. The [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) book seemed to contain patterns that were much more advanced than my use case requires. Any technical advice or recommendations for doing this copying? Possible pitfalls?

Comment: Seems very inefficient. Do you control the external endpoint?

Comment: I have no control on the external endpoint. The external endpoint is incredible slow, so that consulting it through the HTTP interface will harm the performance of my app. It improves the user experience if I have the data on this relational database, queries get much faster.

Comment: Well, one idea is that if you consider to wipe out your entire local database every hour, it might be better to keep your existing tables, make new tables during the import and then do a mass `RENAME TABLE` which should cause no downtime. Personally I think I would prefer to compare the differences and only update records that have changed, but hard to tell from your description whether that's doable.